# Использование Proguard

Tags: java, обфускация, proguard

Как использовать Proguard для своего кода?
Обычная консольная программа.
То ли я не нашёл, то ли и правда в инете нет ни одного нормального гайда по использованию сего чуда обфускации.
Объясните что да как, пожалуйста. Если все таки есть какие-то ***доступные*** мануалы - ткните в них.

Eclipse, Idea -все равно где

Comment: в официальной [документации](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/introduction), есть [руководство по использованию](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage) и есть раздел с [примерами](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/examples)

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, bin/proguard myconfig.pro эту строку куда?

Comment: в руководство по пользованию